# Java regex throwing exception for no match found when pattern found in line

Tags: java, regex

I am dying trying to figure out why a regex won't match. Any help is much appreciated. I'm going line by line of a web page (that works fine), but I need to pull out the links for each line. The application will check to see if there is a link in the line, but I need to actually pull out the URL. help?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*href=\"([^\"]*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(result);
String urlStr = m.group();
links.add(urlStr);
```

The error message I keep getting is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:485)
```

Even though 'result' has a link reference (hxxp://www.yahoo.com) in it.

links is an ArrayList fyi. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out.  The only issue was, my regex had to be

```
".*href=\"([^\"]*?)\".*"
```

Which then made the code

```
private String regex = ".*href=\"([^\"]*?)\".*";
private Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(result);
if (m.matches()) {
    String urlStr = m.group(1);
    links.add(urlStr);
}
```

So that was my issue with the regex, I had to use the '?' to not be greedy I guess!

Answer (score 15):

first call

```
m.find();
```

or

```
m.matches();
```

and then you'll be able to use `m.group()` if matcher succeeded.

Comment: Little explanation. To be able to call `m.group` we first need to call `find` OR `matches` on Matcher instance (`m`). Another important thing is that these methods need to have positive results (they have to return true), so `find` need to be able to find match single match for regex, and `matches` need to be able to confirm that entire input can be matched by regex. Otherwise there will be no match, so there will be nothing in `group` so its state would be illegal.

Comment: So this fixes the error, but it still isn't matching and pulling out URLs.  I can't tell what is wrong with the matching for the URL.  Any suggestions there?

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem and find the minimal input string on which things go wrong. That way you'll most probably find the problem in code. If not - ask another question with [ssce][1]

  [1]: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: So I'm not sure how to be more specific...I have a regex, it doesn't match. Is there something wrong with my regex or is there something i'm doing wrong with Java.  That's my issue.